# valve adjustment 1984 F150 302

Tags: engine, ford, f-150, valve

stock cam, hydraulic lifters. when removing the lash and finding the start of "tension" on the push rod how far should the spring loaded part of the lifter depress before you add the final 1/2 - 3/4 turn

Comment: what do you mean by zero

Answer (score 1):

It should not depress at all before the 3/4 turn, so basically you are finding Zero lash, then add 3/4 turn.

To find zero lash, you roll the push rod with two fingers as you slowly tighten the rocker nut, when you feel increased resistance to rolling it, you have found zero lash.

Comment: It would be good to mention how to find "zero lash". To @TimH : on a pushrod engine, as you are tightening the rocker arm, spin the pushrod. Zero lash is just at the point when the pushrod stops spinning. Add the 1/2 to 3/4 turn at that point.

Comment: I was surprised at how loose the bolt is it the point of no lash and even after 1/2 - 3/4 turn

Comment: they don't sound like adjustable rocker arms..do they have a stud with a nut or just a bolt?